# RXJS sharedReplay does not work when recreating an observable

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

I'm using RXJS websocket for my application. After logging in data is send from my server to the client and the data is stored in an observable using `shareReplay` to keep the data when navigating the application.

```
if(!this.data$ || this.data$Completed) {
    this.data$ = this.dataService.get(this.CTRL, 'list').pipe(
        finalize(() => {
            console.log('finalizing data list');
            this.data$Completed = true;
        }),
        map(data => [....]), // irrelevant
        tap((d) => console.log('data: ', d)),
        shareReplay(1),
        tap((d) => console.log('data 2: ', d)),
    );
}
```

Console output is as intended

```
// first subscribe
data:  [{…}]
data 2:  [{…}]
// every other subscribe when resubscribing after navigation / different components
data 2:  [{…}]
data 2:  [{…}]
data 2:  [{…}]
...
```

When logging off the connection is terminated and the `finalize` method is triggered. When loggin back in the data is send again, but the `shareReplay` does not work anymore. I get data only on the first subscribe, but not after navigating and resubscribing.

```
// logout
finalizing data list

// logging in again
data:  [{…}]
data 2:  [{…}]
```

I also noticed that the rxjs websocket `multiplex` in that case sends subscribe commands to the server, so obvisously I subscribe to the websocket subject and not the ReplaySubject.

Comment: How do you subscribe (or |async) to your rs ? It's not in the code, and remember that a pipe won't do anything by itself, it's the subscribe that "activate" the whole thing.

Comment: I subscribe to the observable using async in my html, but I also tried it with a subscribe call in a component, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

When `finalize` is called, this means that the source `Observable` has completed. You cannot restart a completed `Observable`. The `data$` still emits on subscribe, because that's the idea of `shareReplay`, it just gives you the last emitted value on subscribe, regardless if the source is completed. It will however never get new data.

You will have to recreate your `data$` observable when you login again, to get a new and fresh observable.

Comment: When logging back in the websocket reconnects to the server. A new `WebSocketSubject` is created as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Fussel is this part of the code run `this.data$ = this.dataService.get(this.CTRL, 'list')` when you make a new connection to the server? There can be quite some points where it could go wrong, it's probably better if you also add a small part of your code how you exactly use this `this.data$` in your component, and what the `dataService.get` does

Comment: My mistake was that I did not set `this.data$Completed` to false when creating the observable, only as default value. Thats why it worked only the first time... sometimes it's the little things. =/

Answer (score -2):

I'm kind of rusty with rs and subject in general because I use ngrx for storing data in every app I worked on recently, but the with websockets the logic is a bit different than we classical api, because the websocket itself is a Subject and will recreate itself every time it reconnects. When that happens all the underlying subscription dies. Sadly it means that we cannot use the logic of API calls where a component subscribe to a first observable and a chain of pipes "fires" the api service.

Instead, what we did was to use a subscription directly in the data service that has the ws subject. That's safe because every time the websocket is disconnected, it emits a completed event and thus the subscription dies. This subscription is in charge of pushing the data into the ngrx store by triggering actions, which is basically a call to next.

The service is designed using websocket config option to reconnect every time it loses the connection, and on login. On reco it recreates both a websocket subject and the underlying subscription that push data into ngrx.

Comment: The question does not mention ngrx, why mention that cancer for a question about an app that doesn't use it?

Comment: Whoa, ngrx is a cancer? Really? Anyway, because what we did was using ngrx instead of replay or behavior subjects for the data storage layer. So I talked about it as a kind of disclaimer. However from an architecture perspective, ngrx is just a store and extend the whole private Subject, public asObservable logic, so beside this difference, the same logic we used can be used in its case.

Comment: @AdrianBrand your comment on ngrx puzzle me. I use it extensively, and if there's some know pitfalls I'd rather be educated now than discovering those by myself later. So if you have any comment or blog post or similar to share, don't hesitate.

Comment: So I could make a http request and store the response in a BehaviorSubject in a service as Angular is designed to do. Or I could make a ridiculous amount of boiler plate code across multiple folders so I can dispatch an action that gets caught by a reducer that updates a state in a global store that then gets caught by an effect that does the http request which switchMaps to another action that gets caught by the reducer that updates the global state again.

Comment: It is the most counter intuitive pattern I have ever come across. It sabotages your velocity, steals your employers budget and sentences then to have a giant ramp up period for ever dev that joins the teams. Store patterns solve problems in the React eco system that do not exist in Angular, don't come into the Angular eco system and drag that horrid baggage with you. Learn the Angular dependency injection system and you will never find yourself in need of a store.

Comment: If Google felt Angular needed a store they would have rolled one into the framework by now. Stores add complexity to projects, they most definitely do not solve it.

Comment: You realize that most of the ngrx core dev team is working at Google, including Victor Savkin who developed the Angular dependency injection system, the change detection, the forms and the router ? I do agree about the boiler plate and the hard learning curve for devs, however it all comes down to implementing the reactive paradigm in a more formal way than private subjects and public as.observable() and once you get use to it, it works rather well and give you some nice debug tools like redux.

Comment: I consider using ngrx as a form of malpractice. Once a project is handed over to production support and all the contractors who worked on it have now left how on Earth are production support expected to make changes? You end up having to run up a new project just for minor changes.

Comment: RxJs is the greatest development in UI development I have ever seen. Learning pure Rx is far superior to a convoluted store,

Comment: I suppose it all comes down to the context. I can understand where you're coming from, especially if you're facing a challenge where contractors deliver a code base using librairies unknown to prod support. However in my case, I ran a small company, and we develop for ourselves. When I hire seniors devs, angular and redux are both requisites, so even if they don't know ngrx the transition is super fast. And when I hire juniors, I train them myself and it's much easier to learn ngrx from peers than from docs. I don't have the problem you have because of a different context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228710/discussion-between-jean-xavier-raynaud-and-adrian-brand).